# Fork/Join Sudoku Solver

Tags: java, parallel-processing, sudoku, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I've a problem with an exercise. I need to find all the solutions for a given sudoku, using fork/join parallelism. I made an algorithm but it seems it doesn't work. It stops at some point and I can't figure it out why.

Here's the code:

```
private static int counter;
private Cella[][] sudoku;
private int i;
private int j;
private int theCounter = 0;

public SudokuMulti(Cella[][] sudoku) {
    this.sudoku = sudoku;
}

public SudokuMulti(Cella[][] sudoku, int i, int j) {
    this.sudoku = sudoku;
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
}

//DELETED

// Copy the sudoku matrix
private Cella[][] createCopy() {
    Cella[][] toReturn = new Cella[9][9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(sudoku[i], 0, toReturn[i], 0, 9);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

And the code for the object Cella:

```
public class Cella {

private int current;

public Cella() {
    current = 0;
}

public Cella(int current) {
    this.current = current;
}

//Getter and Setter
```

My idea is to give to each thread the faculty to solve its own sudoku, given the "legal values" of the candidate cell. I then collect all threads in an ArrayList and ask them to fork with the last for. Every thread should return an Integer (0 for no success, 1 for success) in order to count how many possible sudokus can be solved.

However, the algorithm only covers 1/3 of the sudoku: after a certain point, it stops filling the cells and it just returns without completing it.

Can someone suggest me where I'm doing mistake(s) ?

Comment: There are methods and fields used in this method that are not provided in the sample.  This makes it seem likely that these other methods either modify these fields or call other methods, making solving your problem more difficult.  Could you provide the complete class?

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your failure problem, but your loop that spawns multiple solver threads seems to make a terrible mistake.  You create a copy of your current state, but then pass your internal state into the `SudokuMulti` instead of the copy!  That means that the child processes are modifying the caller's state.  I am fairly certain you need that block to be like `Cella[][] copy = createCopy(); copy[I][j].setCurrent(v); forkedThreads.add(new SudokuMulti(copy, i + 1, j).fork());`

Comment: @sadakatsu done, thank you

Comment: @sadakatsu i tried what you suggest, but it doesn't work.

Comment: 1) Your provided code is still incomplete.  For example, `SudokuMulti` does not seem to actually extends `ForthJoinTask` since `compute()` is not a method of that class.  A Minimum Verifiable Example (MVE) would be helpful.  2) Maybe your application is failing because you are queueing something like 81^9 tasks.  Are any `RuntimeException` subclasses thrown by `compute()`?  The documentation for `ForkJoinPool` says, "This implementation rejects submitted tasks (that is, by throwing `RejectedExecutionException`) only when the pool is shut down or internal resources have been exhausted."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Here is the error:

```
// Copy the sudoku matrix
private Cella[][] createCopy() {
    Cella[][] toReturn = new Cella[9][9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        // !!ERROR!!
        System.arraycopy(sudoku[i], 0, toReturn[i], 0, 9);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

When I copy the array I fill it with the Cella object reference and not with a new one, so it causes data races.

The correct way to copy the matrix is:

```
private Cella[][] createCopy() {
    Cella[][] toReturn = new Cella[9][9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            toReturn[i][j] = new Cella(sudoku[i][j].getCurrent());
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what code you have posted, I cannot see any issue that explains your problem.  However, you have not posted code that I can compile and execute myself (known as a Minimum Working or Verifiable Example, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) and [StackOverflow's guide on creating one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), nor have you posted a stack trace or output for your application.  This makes it difficult to help you solve your problem.  If you can provide me with more, I am willing to continue helping you with your problem.

In the meantime, I tried to throw together a program that solves the same problem following your approach.  It seems to work, though I have not thoroughly unit-tested it.  Perhaps you can compare it to what you wrote and use the differences to discover the problem.  You will need at least Java 7 to compile and run this code.

If this is for a homework assignment, I recommend checking with your professor or TA before looking at this listing.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Sudoku puzzle = new Sudoku();
          // Uncomment these lines to have a uniquely solvable Sudoku puzzle.  They are commented out to prove that this code can count multiple solutions.
//        puzzle.set(1, 0, 2);
//        puzzle.set(2, 0, 9);
//        puzzle.set(4, 0, 5);
//        puzzle.set(7, 0, 4);
//        puzzle.set(8, 0, 1);
//        puzzle.set(3, 1, 8);
//        puzzle.set(6, 1, 3);
//        puzzle.set(2, 2, 3);
        puzzle.set(3, 2, 7);
        puzzle.set(4, 2, 4);
        puzzle.set(5, 2, 9);
        puzzle.set(6, 2, 6);
        puzzle.set(3, 3, 4);
        puzzle.set(6, 3, 2);
        puzzle.set(7, 3, 1);
        puzzle.set(1, 4, 6);
        puzzle.set(3, 4, 3);
        puzzle.set(4, 4, 7);
        puzzle.set(5, 4, 1);
        puzzle.set(7, 4, 8);
        puzzle.set(1, 5, 4);
        puzzle.set(2, 5, 1);
        puzzle.set(5, 5, 6);
        puzzle.set(2, 6, 5);
        puzzle.set(3, 6, 9);
        puzzle.set(4, 6, 2);
        puzzle.set(5, 6, 8);
        puzzle.set(6, 6, 7);
        puzzle.set(2, 7, 4);
        puzzle.set(5, 7, 7);
        puzzle.set(0, 8, 3);
        puzzle.set(1, 8, 7);
        puzzle.set(4, 8, 6);
        puzzle.set(6, 8, 5);
        puzzle.set(7, 8, 2);

        SudokuSolver solver = new SudokuSolver(puzzle);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int totalSolutions = solver.compute();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(totalSolutions);
        System.out.format("%f ms", (end - start) / 1e6);
    }

    private static class Sudoku {
        private final int[][] cells;

        Sudoku() {
            cells = new int[9][9];
        }

        Sudoku( Sudoku original ) {
            cells = new int[9][9];
            for (int column = 0; column < 9; ++column) {
                for (int row = 0; row < 9; ++row) {
                    set(column, row, original.get(column, row));
                }
            }
        }

        int get( int column, int row) {
            return cells[column][row];
        }

        void set( int column, int row, int value ) {
            cells[column][row] = value;
        }

        boolean isPlausible() {
            return columnsArePlausible() && rowsArePlausible() && blocksArePlausible();
        }

        private boolean columnsArePlausible() {
            boolean result = true;

            for (int column = 0; result && column < 9; ++column) {
                result = isColumnPlausible(column);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private boolean isColumnPlausible( int column ) {
            boolean result = true;

            boolean[] seen = new boolean[10];
            for (int row = 0; result && row < 9; ++row) {
                int value = get(column, row);
                if (value > 0 && seen[value]) {
                    result = false;
                } else {
                    seen[value] = true;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private boolean rowsArePlausible() {
            boolean result = true;

            for (int row = 0; result && row < 9; ++row) {
                result = isRowPlausible(row);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private boolean isRowPlausible( int row ) {
            boolean result = true;

            boolean[] seen = new boolean[10];
            for (int column = 0; result && column < 9; ++column) {
                int value = get(column, row);
                if (value > 0 && seen[value]) {
                    result = false;
                } else {
                    seen[value] = true;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private boolean blocksArePlausible() {
            boolean result = true;

            for (int column = 0; result && column < 9; column += 3) {
                for (int row = 0; result && row < 9; row += 3) {
                    result = isBlockPlausible(column, row);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private boolean isBlockPlausible( int column, int row ) {
            boolean result = true;

            boolean[] seen = new boolean[10];
            for (int x = 0; result && x < 3; ++x) {
                for (int y = 0; result && y < 3; ++y) {
                    int value = get(column + x, row + y);
                    if (value > 0 && seen[value]) {
                        result = false;
                    } else {
                        seen[value] = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    private static class SudokuSolver extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8759452522630056046L;

        private Sudoku state;
        private int column;
        private int row;

        SudokuSolver( Sudoku state ) {
            this.state = state;
            // These settings allow the search loop in compute() to increment first without asking questions about
            // whether this cell has been checked yet.
            column = -1;
            row = 8;
        }

        SudokuSolver( Sudoku state, int column, int row ) {
            this.column = column;
            this.row = row;
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer compute() {
            int viableSolutions = 0;

            if (state.isPlausible()) {
                int originalColumn = column;
                int originalRow = row;

                do {
                    if (row + 1 >= 9) {
                        ++column;
                        row = 0;
                    } else {
                        ++row;
                    }
                } while (column < 9 && state.get(column, row) != 0);

                if (column >= 9) {
                    viableSolutions = 1;
                } else {
                    List<SudokuSolver> solvers = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int value = 1; value <= 9; ++value) {
                        Sudoku copy = new Sudoku(state);
                        copy.set(column, row, value);
                        solvers.add(new SudokuSolver(copy, column, row));
                    }
                    invokeAll(solvers);
                    for (SudokuSolver solver : solvers) {
                        viableSolutions += solver.join();
                    }
                }
            }

            return viableSolutions;
        }
    }
}
```

Since this code times how long it takes to count the solutions, the output can vary, but I got

```
354
709.848410 ms
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I figure it out what is the problem and it's very awkward. It doesn't work because of a mistake in the copy process of the matrix. When I copy the array I fill it with the `Cella` object reference and not with a new one, so it causes data races.